# Styling a SWT label to be italic

Tags: java, swt

How would I go about styling a SWT label created along the following lines so it is displayed italicised?

```
Label label = formToolkit.createLabel(composite, "My label name");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a new [Font](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Font.html) object.

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
label.setText("I am italic");
FontData fontData = label.getFont().getFontData()[0];
Font font = new Font(display, new FontData(fontData.getName(), fontData
    .getHeight(), SWT.ITALIC));
label.setFont(font);
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}
font.dispose();
display.dispose();
```

Comment: And just to think, people said Java was too verbose

Answer (score 19):

It would be better to use `FontRegistry` class from `JFaces`, like this:

```
label.setFont(
    JFaceResources.getFontRegistry().getItalic(JFaceResources.DEFAULT_FONT)
);
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this helper class will automatically dispose all requested fonts. So you no longer need to keep references around to dispose them, which is a nice bonus on top of the brevity of this solution.

Comment: Just a small correction: while using an empty string achieves the same effect, the "correct" way to get the default italic font would be `getItalic(JFaceResources.DEFAULT_FONT)`

Answer (score 3):

A [recent article](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/02/10/swt-best-practices-changing-fonts/) (February 2014 from [Jordi Böhme López](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/author/jordi/)) suggest another way to get the current font in order to modify it:

> it’s like getting the blueprint of the default font, making some changes and building a new font with the modified blueprint:

```
Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
FontDescriptor descriptor = FontDescriptor.createFrom(label.getFont());
// setStyle method returns a new font descriptor for the given style
descriptor = descriptor.setStyle(SWT.BOLD);
label.setFont(descriptor.createFont(label.getDisplay));
label.setText("Bold Label");
```

Comment: it seems you have to do something like descriptor = descriptor.setStyle(SWT.BOLD);   This is more a create() than a set() method

Comment: This solution does not work 1:1 unfortunately. Can't find the fix either.

Comment: the setStyle method returns a new font descriptor for the given style, so better descriptor = descriptor.setStyle(SWT.BOLD) e.g.

Comment: @kewlbfy Interesting. I have edited the answer accordingly. Does it look more accurate?

Comment: yes, keep in mind that the descriptor.createFont method does call the Font constructor directly, so unlike the expected design of disposables that have to be disposed in case of a constructor call, the font created here also has to be disposed. maybe add it to the fontregistry

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work:

```
Label lblSample = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER_SOLID);
lblSample.setFont(new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font(null, "Times New Roman", 12, SWT.BOLD | SWT.ITALIC));
lblSample.setText("Enter Text Here");
```